# Partial-screen video preview distorted regardless of UIViewContentMode selection

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, avfoundation

I'm trying to make a simple app which will show in the top half of the iphone screen a raw preview of what the back camera sees, while in the bottom half the same preview but with various filters applied.

I first got the raw preview part working, not too hard thanks to several SO and blog posts. The UIImageView I'm displaying to takes up the entire screen for that part.

To get a half-screen view I just divide the image view's height by two, then set its contentMode to show everything while keeping the same aspect ratio:

```
imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2))

imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

The height reduction works, but the image in the view is compressed vertically (e.g. a coin viewed straight-on looks like a horizontal oval). I don't think it's a coincidence that the appearance of the preview looks like the contentMode default ScaleToFill, but nothing I've tried changes the mode.

The complete code is below - the project has one scene with one view controller class; everything's done programatically.

Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
{
    var imageView : UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

        view.addSubview(imageView)

        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

        let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        do
        {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
            captureSession.addInput(input)
        }
        catch
        {
            print("Camera not available")
            return
        }

        // Unused but required for AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate:captureOutput() events to be fired
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_queue_create("SampleBufferDelegate", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL))

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput)
        {
            captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
        }

        videoOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait

        captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
    {

        let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        let cameraImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(CIImage: cameraImage)
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this line has problem because it is in `viewDidLoad()` method.

Not sure it is related to your issue but I feel this is important note to you.

```
imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2))
```

You can not get correct view's size in `viewDidLoad()` function.

Furthermore, from iOS 10, I found controls are initially sized `(0, 0, 1000, 1000)` from storyboard before they are correctly laid out by iOS layout engine.

Also, the size you get in `viewDidLoad()` can be size of view controller in storyboard.  So if you laid out controls in 4 Inch screen, it will return size of 4 inch screen in `viewDidLoad()` method even you run the app on iPhone6 or bigger screens.

Also, please set `imageView.layer.maskToBounds` property to true to prevent any out bounding of image.

One more thing is that you should place code laying out your image view appropriately when the view bounds changes (Like rotation of screen).

Comment: Thanks, Alex. These aren't points I'm familiar with yet, since I'm new to iOS programming.